# List is not centered with Flexbox on smaller screen sizes

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

At 600 pixels my flexbox turns into a column. The list in the second box is not centered correctly on smaller screen sizes. I have tried adding margins and padding all over the place, in and out of media queries.  It sits too far to the right. When I adjust the width it seems stuck to the left side. How do I fix this?

```css
/* FLEXBOX */

.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  padding: 5px;
}


/* Table and Cell for Vertical Alignment */

.table {
  display: table;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* SHOWCASE  */

#showcase {
  background-color: #1d2120;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

#showcase h1 {
  padding-top: 0px;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #da5d61;
}

#showcase h2 {
  color: #bcd5d1;
  font -family: Cairo;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}

#showcase h3 {
  color: #ba9077;
  font-family: Cairo;
  font-size: 1em;
}

#inline {
  font-size: 3em;
}

#inline li {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .flexbox {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #contact .container {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 610px) {
  .flexbox {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #contact .container {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- SHOWCASE -->
<header id="showcase">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="flexbox">

      <div class="box text-center">
        <h1 class="text animated pulse">Ellis Smith</h1>
        <h2><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Copywriter</h2>
        <h3>Quality copy, never copied.</h3>
      </div>
      <!-- /box -->

      <nav class="box">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#testimonials-placeholder">Testimonials</a>
            <li>
              <a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- /box -->
    </div>
    <!-- /flexbox -->
  </div>
  <!-- /cell -->
</header>
<!-- /showcase -->

<!--/END SHOWCASE -->
```

Comment: Hmm... why wouldn't you want to use Bootstrap for this if you are already using Bootstrap anyway? Everything in Bootstrap 4 is flexbox-based and adding custom css hacks while using Bootstrap is generally not a good idea  because it tends to require more css hacks to fix the problems caused by the original css hacks.

Comment: Good point. So I could remove the flexbox and put a bootstrap grid inside the table's cell?

Comment: Yes, you can do absolutely everything with Bootstrap alone and no, you shouldn't put that into a table cell. Table cells have very rare application cases. Just a normal row-column pair. I'll post something in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

To handle this issue in Bootstrap 4, you'd simply create a row-column pair and put your content inside the column.

If you only have one list that you want to center, then I recommend using the `col-auto` class for that column (it automatically changes the width of the column to fit the content) and then add the class `mx-auto` (margin horizontal auto) to that. That will center the column.

Here's the code snippet for that (note: that code snippet assumes that you put the whole thing into a Bootstrap `.container` or `.container-fluid`):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto mx-auto">
        <nav class="box">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#testimonials-placeholder">Testimonials</a>
                <li>
                    <a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav><!-- /box -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are two boxes inside my flexbox. How would you incorporate the first box:

<div class="box text-center">
          <h1 class="text animated pulse">Ellis Smith</h1>
          <h2><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Copywriter</h2>
          <h3>Quality copy, never copied.</h3>

        </div><!-- /box -->

Comment: How will this center on my page without the table and cell. You said I could remove that as well right?

Comment: Yes, remove the table cell. As for the other box: The centering can be done exactly the same way. The question is: Do you want these boxes to appear that way on all screen sizes?